# Java convention for class field definition in constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, coding-style, convention

**The question**: What difference do these 2 styles have? Is one preferred over the other, why?

If I have field variables that I define with parameters of a constructor, I usually do this as I do in C++ :

```
public class Thingamajing{ 
    private int var1, var2;

    public Thingamajing(int var1_ , int var2_ ){
       var1 = var1_; 
       var2 = var2_; 
    }
}
```

But in a lot of Java examples online, I find this style:

```
public class Thingamajing{ 
    private int var1, var2;

    public Thingamajing(int var1 , int var2 ){
       this.var1 = var1; 
       this.var2 = var2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Opinion based, but having `this.` prefix a variable gives it immediate recognition that it is a class field.

Comment: 2nd style. follow the convention, so that others can read your code easier. unless, you don't want others to read your code.

Comment: You have to do it that way in C++ because you have to disambiguate the actual field names from the parameters when using initializer syntax in constructors. You don't have that problem in Java so there is no need to do it. Use `this`.